# How to find the first cell with a specific value in each row?

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula or macro that will return the first cell in which a specified value occurs by row. For example, Column A would be EMPLOYEE NAME, Column B would be MANAGER LEVEL 1, Column C would be MANAGER LEVEL 2.... so on. Some managers are certified, which will be indicated by their name - Brian (Certified) or Brian if not certified.

Using the above example, I want to find the lowest level manager who is certified for each employee. That is, ColumnF results as shown under the header:

[image]

Comment: Here is a photo example - I included a "Target Answer" Column to show what the accurate response is http://s28.postimg.org/nro4973bh/Capture.png

Comment: =INDEX(A2:E2,MATCH("*(Certified)*",A2:D2,0)) worked perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Function findCertified(row As Integer)
    findCertified = Sheet1.Rows(row).Find("(Certified)").Value
End Function
```